How to analyze differences in growth data with non-normal distributions?
I have data on fungal growth (growth rate and latency period) from different strains. I want to examine whether these values differ based on origin (2 types), growth medium (2 types), and incubation at different temperatures, including interactions between factors.
The issue is that I cannot use ANOVA because the data is not normally distributed, and since I have multiple factors to compare, the Kruskal-Wallis test isn't an option either.
Moreover, PERMANOVA is not suitable because the assumption of homogeneous dispersion is not met. The distribution of the data is trimodal, and I tried splitting the data into subsets based on temperature, but this approach did not make much difference. How can I analyze these differences effectively?

A linear regression model sounds like the most logical option (equivalent to ANOVA). The data not being normally distributed is not a problem, it is not an assumption. The only assumption is that the outcome is normal conditional on the regressors. In plain words, the residuals must be normally distributed. So fit the model and then check the disitrbution of the residuals using e..g a qq-plot, you'll find plenty of examples on this in textbooks and online.

Thanks for your contribution. The speed and latency data come from a non-linear regression, whose residuals follow a normal distribution. However, when combining these coefficients into a new data frame for comparative analysis and performing a linear regression with the two as variables, the residuals are no longer normal. It is these coefficients that are intended to be compared with the environmental factors to examine differences across different levels of the factors.


When you say the dispersion is trimodal I am unclear exactly what you mean. If you mean the variable itself is trimodal, are you looking at the marginal distribution of the response (ignoring the three predictors? If so that is of no consequences, since ANOVA makes no assumption about the marginal distribution of the response variable. 2. Even if it were the conditional distribution that were trimodal, it might not be particularly consequential.  3. If you mean something else by dispersion being trimodal, please clarify.


Apologies for the confusion earlier. I meant to say that the distribution is trimodal, referring specifically to the marginal distribution. However, after running the code, I found that the distribution of the residuals is not normal. I'll add the code in another comment

hist(data$Coeficient_u, breaks = 30, col = "lightblue", main = "Distribution")
plot(density(data$Coeficient_u), main = "Distribution", col = "blue", lwd = 2)
model <- aov(Coeficient_u ~ Origen, data = data) #Origen is a factor
summary(modelo)
qqnorm(residuals(model))
qqline(residuals(model))
shapiro.test(residuals(model)) #Where p-value = 3.557e-16
library(car)
leveneTest(Coeficient_u ~ Origen, data = data) #but p-value: 0.3024

Please add newinfo as an edit to the post, and not only as a comment. Comments on this site are often seen only by a few, and can be deleted.  Can you also show us some plots of the data?

As I often note in such questions, the wording implies a wrong conception of model assumptions. Model assumptions are idealised constructs and do generally not hold in the real world. Therefore it isn't correct to say that "ANOVA can only be applied if residuals are normal" and the like. In fact it is applied all the time with non-normal residuals, and perfectly normal residuals do not exist. The important (but somewhat difficult to assess) issue is whether deviations from model assumptions are of such a kind that they are likely to mislead the conclusions from the analysis.

Inference based on normality is fine in many non-normal cases because of the Central Limit Theorem (although there are exceptions such as situations with gross outliers).

As comments note, you might be able to proceed with a linear regression/ANOVA model despite the "statistically significant" non-normality of residuals around your model predictions. Without seeing the qqplot and plots of residuals against predicted values, it's hard to judge.
If a standard linear model turns out not to be appropriate, you can consider ordinal regression. A proportional-odds ordinal model handles multiple predictors and interactions and can be considered a generalization of the Kruskal-Wallis test. Ordinal regression works with the rank-ordering of outcome observations without making any assumptions about their distribution or the distribution of residuals. Although the method is usually presented for small numbers of outcome levels, as in this UCLA web page, Frank Harrell's rms package in R has an orm() function that can efficiently handle up to a few thousand different outcome levels.
